# How do I install uTorrent?

Tags: 12.04, installation, utorrent

I have tried all the tutorials to install uTorrent, but I still can't get any of them to work.
They are all identical. Basically, you get the .tar.gz file, unzip it to /opt/, mark it as executable, link it to /usr/bin/utserver, install libssl0.9.8, and run it.

I've done all this, but here's what I get:

```
utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/
bash: /usr/sbin/utserver: No such file or directory
```

So, I tried this:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver /usr/sbin/utserver
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/sbin/utserver': File exists
```

So, the utserver command says that the directory/file doesn't exist, but the ln command says it does. What's the problem? (I've already tried rebooting. For a while after a reboot, the command utserver doesn't return any errors; it just exits.)